# How to isolate MCU ground with a high-side driver?

Tags: microcontroller

I've got an application where I am controlling a bunch of high-pressure 24 V DC valves using GPIO outputs on an ARM-based MCU.

The MCU is also monitoring pressure transducers, transmitting data via serial/UART and more.

My PCB has a number of different battery inputs and voltage regulators for the various components.

In the past, I was sloppy with using common ground returns that caused noise between the solenoid valves and the pressure transducer readings. So now I am re-evaluating my entire ground/return strategy to isolate as much as I can, at least across the different components and voltages.

I do have good flyback diodes on the inductive solenoids, but the high-side drivers I am using to switch the 24 VDC shares a ground with the MCU (5 V/3.3 V).

The high-side driver I am using is an ST VNQ660SPTR-E. It is a quad switch that is perfect for the application, but it requires a shared ground. Low-side switching isn't really an option, as we have a lot of lines going to valves on a bi-propellant rocket, so we'd prefer to keep them all cold to prevent an accidental short to ground on the vehicle.

Any suggestions on how to get this driver to work, while isolating the MCU ground? Here is a application diagram from the datasheet that generally describes how I am using it in our circuit:

[image]

Comment: is the problem really in the stable DC ground return current? Are you experiencing glitches at swith time or what exactly?

Comment: This question is muddled. The first half of the question has little to do with the second half. Isolating for noise purposes has nothing to do with floating a ground referenced device.

Comment: Yep. Fair points regarding the question being muddled. To clarify... I am not currently having specific known issues with this driver-MCU ground configuration, BUT a different part of my circuit was having issues (now resolved), so it has forced me to reconsider and re-evaluate ALL of my shared supply and grounds across the circuit. For example, I now have dedicated power supply and returns going to the radio, I've got pressure transducers on separate ADCs with their own supply and returns. This driver stood out during my review as "high risk", but is not specifically an issue now.

Answer (score 2):

Take note of where the diagram appears.

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vnq660sp.pdf

> GND protection network against reverse battery

This is an automotive part, which is rated to withstand traditional automotive transients (ISO 7637/1, see Table 12).  These include supply reversal.

If your application will not experience supply reversal, you do not need to follow this section.  Tie GND to system GND.

Your noise issues will be addressed by separating current loops and shielding magnetic fields, not by isolating ground connections per se.

Answer (score 1):

For noise purposes (as well as safety purposes), there is no point in isolating *just* the ground. This is likely to make the noise even worse. It's the same reason you don't split the ground plane on a PCB. The noise and return currents *will* find their way around and if you eliminate their preferred path without providing an easier path, they will follow a more difficult path while being more disruptive as it needs to force it's way through the more difficult path.

There is no point in putting up a barrier if you leave a side door open. If you want to isolate the MCU from the gate driver you need to isolate EVERYTHING that runs between the two. This includes both signals and power, and the entire chain of devices connected to the MCU and gate driver. The entire circuit would need to be clearly divided into two halves and everything that crosses between the halves must travel through a form of isolation.

If you know interrupting current through coils is your problem then use RC snubbers (in place of or in addition to your flyback diodes). Flyback diodes do not alleviate noise. Flyback diodes clamp the flyback voltage to a set value regardless of the strength of the spike, but do not slow down the edge which is the source of the noise. RC snubbers slow down the edge and reduce the voltage peak of the spike; That is, they do not clamp the peak. A more powerful spike will have a higher peak but the peak will be reduced from what it otherwise would have been.

You may also use gate resistors to slow down the MOSFET transition which will somewhat do the same thing, except this will also influence the turn-on which can be important.

---

But at the same time, the first half of your question body doesn't match your second half. It sounds like you want to float a ground-referenced device so you can use it on the high-side. This is unrelated and not the same thing as the noise concerns you led with. But even if you float the ground all the input signals going to the switch are ground referenced so you will need to shift that reference as well (such as with opto-isolators and for this purpose it follows looser guidelines that the strict isolation mentioned for noise or safety purposes).

As a result, your question is muddled and needs clearing up about what it is you really want. These are two separate issues.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. It validates what I suspected. I will look at snubbers. I had not considered them.

Answer (score 0):

1. You might want to connect MCU GND and the driver GND pins directly (with least impedance).
2. You might want to separate the valve current loop from the GPIO current loop as much as possible, which leads to a star GND connection point directly at the driver GND pin.
3. Consider optical isolation.

Comment: I am currently doing #2, so the current paths don't overlap (except within the driver chip). Is that enough?  I considered optical isolation, but I'd have to isolate EVERYTHING -- basically drive optos from the GPIO pins and the switch side of the optos power the drivers. In my last iteration of the PCB I drove the valves with Opto relays, but they get expensive and are limited in terms of capabilities.

Comment: Yes, #2 should be enough. But you really need to check that the "load loop" has no shared segments with the "control loop" (=Galvanic isolation). And then you need to check that the load loop can not induce currents into the control loop. (=Minimize inductive coupling).